# How start watchman in react-native project

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, watchman

I've create my first react-native app with `react-native init myProject` and running in my android emulator.

But, if i edit my index.js, my app don't refresh (i need to push double R).

I run my app with `react-native run-android` and server with `npm start`.

watchman is installed on my Ubuntu, `watchman -v` return :

`4.9.0`

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable 'Live Reload'.

**On Physical device:**

Shake the device and then choose 'Enable Live Reload' from the menu.

**On the simulator:**

When the Android simulator is open:

```
cmd (ctrl on Windows) + m
```

ios simulator:

```
cmd + d
```

and then choose 'Enable Live Reload' from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else lands here who couldn't work out if watchman was running properly or not, in my case the issue was my `.git` directory. Although according to the docs `.git/` is meant to be ignored by default, Watchman was clearly hanging whenever I saved a file, and subsequently the live reload didn't work. Adding this to my `.watchmanconfig` fixed it:

```
{
  "ignore_dirs": [".git"]
}
```